# intent when user tries to delete a file from gallery

Tags: android, file, android-intent

What i am trying to do is that if a user tries to delete a file from gallery , he will be asked if he want to delete it using my app.
I was looking if there is an intent call that can be captured when user tries to delete file from the gallery.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such an intent.
But in order to check if there is one, check the logcat while deleting the file. All the intents are shown in the logcat while they are launched. I suggest you to write 'intent' in the search line of the logcat (at the top) and check this.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Maybe you should register to the Broadcast Receiver as a service.

Comment: thanks for your help , i found out that well its no possible and 1 up for pointer for checking of intent in logcat :)